# Budget Analysis Form Rightside grid should defaultly open when i Open the form for single project. Dynamics ax

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

In Budget Analysis form, When we open the form it shows list of projects on left side grid. Then when we select value on left side grid then only the Grid on Right hand side is getting filled. If I have only one project on Left hand side, is there any way i can get right hand side grid populated for that project at the time when i open the form??

I tried bringing the code from selection changed  method of lefthand side grid to 
init method of form, but i am getting some difficulty with tree nodes etc.

Can someone suggest me a best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following two changes for version AX 2012 R3. I would guess that this would also work in other AX 2012 versions. I could not find any budget analysis in AX 2009 and I doubt it exists there because it is part of the retail module which has been introduced in AX 2012.

First, customize the building of the tree control such that the first child will get selected instead of the root. To do that, customize method `initTreeControl` of class `BudgetAnalysisInquiryHelper_PSN` and add the following line after the tree has been expanded:

```
_formTreeControl.select(_formTreeControl.getChild(_formTreeControl.getRoot()));
```

Now that the correct node in the tree is selected, the `getBudgetSummary` method of form `BudgetAnalysisInquiry_PSN` can be called to update the grid. To do this after the form has been opened, put the following lines at the end of method `run` (basically the same lines as in method `selectionChanged` of the tree control):

```
selectedNode = ctrlDimensionTree.getItem(ctrlDimensionTree.getSelection());
budgetAnalysisDimensionNode = selectedNode.data();
ctrlSelectedNode.text(budgetAnalysisDimensionNode.getNodeText());
element.getBudgetSummary(ctrlDimensionTree);
```

Calling these lines in method `init` is too early because method `run` (which is executed after `init`) calls method `refreshGrids` which deletes the data in the temporary data sources of the form.

Comment: This worked, but when I refresh the cache in AX and when I tried to open the form: SelectedNode is getting null value and I am getting error at  Line B: "FormTreeItem object not initialized. Stack trace Forms\FormName\Methods\Run"                                                                                               LineA: selectedNode = ctrlDimensionTree.getItem(ctrlDimensionTree.getSelection());
LineB: budgetAnalysisDimensionNode = selectedNode.data();                So I have commented Line A and Line B and hardcoded text in ctrlSelectedNode.text("HardcodedExpectedText");Any inputs ?

Comment: @Raas: Could you create a new question for that and describe in more detail how this can be reproduced? I'm not sure what you mean with "when I refresh the cache in AX", since AX has a lot of different caches.